# Does ajax call slows down the frontend?

Tags: javascript, ajax, performance, spring-mvc, jquery-ui-autocomplete

i have the below scenario:

1. There is an arraylist of Java Pojo which stores data from db. The pojo has 3 fields and after fetching the data from db, the size of arralist is 250. I am storing that data in application scope. Its a spring mvc application.
2. I have created an end point in a controller class which filters the arralist using collection streams and returns the list of string as json.
3. I have implemented **jquery autocomplete** at frontend jsp and javascript, and i am fetching the source from this end point through ajax call.

My question is, whether ajax call approach is good or should i filter the data at the javascript code only.

After implementing ajax, the xhr call is taking on an average 300ms in local.

Note: IE11 support is also needed.

Comment: ajax is async, therefore it shouldn't slow down front end. However each browser handles differently network activity

Comment: and for the Note: IE11 Ajax is also suported